# CakePHP or CodeIgniter for file sharing webapp?

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications, amazon-s3, cakephp-2.2

I am building a web app designed to provide users with file-sharing ability, this is a safe app as the service is paid and will be using **Stripe Payment API**

However I can't decide which php framework would be the best for this task. I am very clear that this can be done with both, but I want the framework to be light on the server and not eat allot of server resources like RAM and CPU as I am limited at this moment, but should the app grow higher then resources will be increased.

I looked at Code Igniter and CakePHP. In my view CakePHP seems much more lighter then CodeIngiter but I never used either one so I can't judge. All I need the framework to do is

- Provide up-most security possible against XSS, Injections
- Able to work with file system and amazon s3
- Play nice with amazon s3 and provide easy upload method to s3
- Provide simple template scheme
- Provide fastest possible database and general response time
- Work with Stripe Payment API
- Work with PHP 5.3.x and MySQL 5.3.x as efficiently

This is really it, if you can provide some pro feedback on which one would do the best or just do great for the task of file-sharing and dealing with files in s3 please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something small go for Yii if it is still small at all or any other micro framework. The questions is if it offers you everything you need to get it done in time and is solid.

Cake had just two security issues in the last few years AFAIR, the latest one (1 year ago) [has just hit ruby on rails](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ/discussion). It is solid and has thousands of unit tests for the core.

What is a template scheme for you? Something like twig? There are plugins for virtually any template engine. But template engines are a waste of resources. Go for plain php/html views. I know that some template engines support caching to increase performance but thats pointless because cake already offers caching techniques and also full page caching. So you can cache any output. If you want to go for OOP views checkout the [Ctk plugin](https://github.com/jameswatts/cake-toolkit) for Cake.

I've written [a plugin for storing files](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) in any kind of storage system. It supports more storage engines than the few you list. And it was exactly written for the task you ask for. I'm storing files first locally and move them to S3 later.

I don't know if there is any free available plugin for the stripe API, I think you'll have to do a little coding own your own... ;) If you go for cake you can [use this plugin](https://github.com/burzum/Payments) as a base and maybe you would like to make it open source, in this case I would help you with it. But I'm sure that any php framework can made to work with this API.

Comment: interesting plugin for the S3 you got there.

Answer (score 2):

There are not much new improvement done in CodeIgniter. To take advantage of the new PHP 5.3, I would recommend you to use CakePHP instead. They are actively working in version 3 which will fully support 5.3 .

The following post might help you making a good decision.
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/05/laravel-is-awesome

Comment: philsturgeon is quite the programmer, I really trust his work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest codeigniter. I have used both heavily and I really have a lot of issues with Cake. Cake is not the lighter of the two, I found that Cake wants you to do things cakes way otherwise you are in for a really sore time. This is not really how a framework should work. Codeigniter on the other hand hs a framework to support you but allows you to write unobstructed php all day as you need it. Cake is really good at getting in the way and has a much steeper learning curve. Codeigniter will let you do all of those things you need, I know for instance that there are handy functions like `$this->security->xss_clean($your_data);` that return data cleaned of xss issues. So its support for stuff like that is super handy. Templating is less robust in codeigniter, but the reason I like codeigniter is that it stays out of your way and lets you code PHP. This is good, because you know how to code in PHP, whereas when you code in Cake, you are writing weird cake code. This has the nasty side effect of making the code hard to manage should more people come on to the team and its impossible to ask people who do not know cake for help with cake stuff. Also cake does not guarantee backwards compatibility, your installation is your forever, if you use say version 1.6 then it might not be possible for you to move to 2.0 without serious rewrites (which seems short sighted on their part.)

Cake will offer you more features though, so if your in a hurry it will help you along with large parts of the setup, provided your always cool with doing everything its way. If your not the best at database stuff cake totally abstracts that away. I personally hate that, because I'm serious about db fine-tuning and lots of things I want to do to make better use of the db cake just flat-out forbids. Codeigniter's freedom why it is the one I would pick. Its docs are great two. Oh yeah the docs. Codeignite's docs are so much better than cake, so that is a good reason to pick it too.

Comment: CakePHP actually beats even Yii in performance if properly used and as silly tested as Yii did to claim its performance crown. And your're totally wrong: Convention over configuration IS how things should work and intended to work. And nothing keeps you from doing it your way, you just have to configure a lot and use additional params. Don't blame the framework if you dont understand its principles. Also your security example: In Cake add the Security component, done. You dont even need to call a method for that.

Comment: Oh and documentation. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html Whats wrong with that extensive documentation? When did you look the last time at Cake? 2 Year ago? The 1.3 documentation was indeed not that good but 2.0 is superior.

Comment: Actually, yes, is was about 2 years ago.

Comment: Honestly, then you should not judge the actual version of it based on a two year old experience that also implies that you have not done much with it.

Comment: @IamJohnGalt I can't agree with you more I found it fairly annoying ones I opened up cake template files for the actually pages and what did i see? __d(code code) this kind of syntax is just plain stupid and in a way will make huge mess as this is fairly large project with allot of code.

Comment: @burzum actually Yii seemed to have had a bigger file size I also considered Laravel Framework. But as I said Yii seemed-ed to be bigger of the two aw 23.xx MB, and from I read people are not very found of CakePHP. So I will probably go with CI or Laravel in the long term.

Comment: @CI' What is stupid in using an abbreviated version of these http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php standard methods? If you care about clean views go for the CTK plugin I've told you and do them OOP style, thats the right way to go for maintaining large projects.

Comment: @IamJohnGalt to be honest John, Cake reminds me of PERL ones it becomes a total hacked together mess ones the code becomes larger and larger. Also would you recommend Laravel or Symphony? If not I will just go with CI or Laravel as I do have a developer on my team familiar with LARAVEL and he said its pretty amazing

Comment: @burzum OOP can become a mess on its own, not mentioning that this project got 3 developers of different skill level and the way they write code in general. Having odd syntax which I never seen before trying out CakePHP was annoying. It took me seconds to create new pages with CI and I did not have such luck with CakePHP.

Comment: @CI' This syntax is not odd, it's an abbreviation for the gettext translation tool, a de-facto standard used by thousands of open and closed source applications and not only web apps. You prefer silly huge translation arrays or constants without the gettext benefits? Well go for it. ANd why do you blame a clean and structured framework if your application code becomes a huge mess? Bad programmers cause a mess with any framework and language.

Comment: @CI' I have never used those frameworks so I cannot really say. I do love codeigniter though, and if your team has a bunch of people with difference skill levels then using a general framework is a good idea. That way you guys can focus on PHP. If you would like, some of the very talented people who built codeigniter went on to build this which is also getting good reviews: http://www.fuelphp.com/

Comment: @CI' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext - and by a quick research CI does not even implement a proper I10n solution. What about support of plurals for example? This is just a file loader for an array. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html You really want to do some research on I10n and I18n.

Comment: @burzum I have no problem going with Yii then and I will have l10n and l18n support as well, but with no __d

Comment: @IamJohnGalt actually I seen more and more articles pooping up about FuelPHP played with it today also seems like a great framework.